# How to get route from twig extension class

Tags: symfony

```
class AdminExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
   // content...
}
```

I'm extending twig functionality by adding a class that adds new twig method. Inside this method I want to use current route. How can I do that?

I mean, for example, having:

```
www.someurl.com/prefix/controller1/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd
```

I want to get `controller1/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd` part inside the function I described.

Thanks!

Comment: Your `Twig_Extension` class should be defined as a service, and then you can inject the `request` service right there, though you might catch stumble into some service scope problems.
Then, the `request` service has a `getRequestUri()` method that will return exactly what its name states.

Comment: Indeed, I'm injecting RouterInterface service, but how to get what I described from that?

Comment: You need the `request`, not the `router`.

Comment: Try `getUri()` method from the same `Request` class: http://api.symfony.com/2.5/index.html?q=HttpFoundation\Request#method_getRequestUri

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should register the extension as a service and then inject `request_stack` (as of Symfony 2.4) in the service:

```
my_extension:
    class: ...
    arguments: ["@request_stack"]
    tags: [{ name: twig.extension }]
```

Then you can get the request by using `RequestStack#getCurrentRequest()` and you can get the current url by using `Request#getUri()`.

Comment: Ok, but what if the uri is empty, like www.someurl.com/controller1/ and the default route is being used? Request stack will return empty string, while it should return the default route...

Comment: @user3486978 When the url is `someurl.com/controller1/` and the front controller is in `someurl.com/`, `Request#getPathInfo()` would return `/controller1/`

Comment: but if default route is /path/1, the url is someurl.com/controller1/, it should return /controller1/path/1, and not /controller1/.

Comment: Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Can you please define "default route"?

Comment: Set as default in controller's annotations.